# Multiple elements -> one function while the elements do not colide with each other

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, velo

I have multiple selectiontags on different picture slides but same page. Each slide has a set of selectiontags and I want users to only choose 1 selectiontag. I have written the code to do this but I wonder if there is another way.
So, basically I want:

- Slide1 w. selectiontags1: Choose 1 selectiontag (out of 4)
- Slide2 w.selectiontags2: Choose 1 selectiontag
- Slide3 w. selectiontags3: Choose 1 selectiontag
- Slide4 w. selectiontags4: Choose 1 selectiontag

This is my code so far.

```
var prevSelectedValue = null;
var prevSelectedValue2 = null;
var prevSelectedValue3 = null;
var prevSelectedValue4 = null;


$w.onReady(function () {
    //TODO: write your page related code here...
    let tags = $w('#selectionTags1');
    if (tags.value.length === 1) {
        prevSelectedValue = tags.value[0];
    } else if (tags.value.length > 1) {
        tags.value = [];
    }
    let tags2 = $w('#selectionTags2');
    if (tags2.value.length === 1) {
        prevSelectedValue2 = tags2.value[0];
    } else if (tags2.value.length > 1) {
        tags2.value = [];
    }
    let tags3 = $w('#selectionTags3');
    if (tags3.value.length === 1) {
        prevSelectedValue3 = tags3.value[0];
    } else if (tags3.value.length > 1) {
        tags3.value = [];
    }
    let tags4 = $w('#selectionTags4');
    if (tags4.value.length === 1) {
        prevSelectedValue4 = tags4.value[0];
    } else if (tags4.value.length > 1) {
        tags4.value = [];
    }
});

export function selectionTags1_change(event) {
    //Add your code for this event here: 
    if (!event.target.value || event.target.value.length === 0) {
        event.target.value = [prevSelectedValue];
    } else {
        event.target.value = event.target.value.filter(x => x !== prevSelectedValue);
        prevSelectedValue = event.target.value[0];
    }
}

export function selectionTags2_change(event) {
    //Add your code for this event here:
    if (!event.target.value || event.target.value.length === 0) {
        event.target.value = [prevSelectedValue2];
    } else {
        event.target.value = event.target.value.filter(x => x !== prevSelectedValue2);
        prevSelectedValue2 = event.target.value[0];
    } 
}
export function selectionTags3_change(event) {

    //Add your code for this event here: 
    if (!event.target.value || event.target.value.length === 0) {
        event.target.value = [prevSelectedValue3];
    } else {
        event.target.value = event.target.value.filter(x => x !== prevSelectedValue3);
        prevSelectedValue3 = event.target.value[0];
    } 
}

export function selectionTags4_change(event) {
    //Add your code for this event here: 
    if (!event.target.value || event.target.value.length === 0) {
        event.target.value = [prevSelectedValue4];
    } else {
        event.target.value = event.target.value.filter(x => x !== prevSelectedValue4);
        prevSelectedValue4 = event.target.value[0];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple notes to help clean up the code:

- It is better to use `event.target.value[event.target.value.length-1]` instead of `.filter()`. While it doesn't make a huge performance difference since our array is so small, we know that the most recently selected item is the last in the array, so using `length-1` is more efficient code.
- It is better to manipulate the selector and not the event, so I would recommend replacing `event.target.value = event.target.value.filter...` with `$w('#selectionTags2') = event.target.value[....`. This will also make your code more readable as you know which element is being updated.
- If you are not preloading anything into the `$w('#selectionTags')` value array, I am not sure the code in your onReady function is necessary (unless I am missing a step where you do populate that selection value array).